# Convert RxJava Subjects to Observables

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-viewmodel

I recently ran into discussion about usage of `Subject`, like this one here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/issues/7

I see a lot of people saying that `Subject` should be avoided and some people even say *any* usage of `Subject` is inherently a bad practice. While I agree on the theoretical level that `Subject` can be and should be avoided, I can hardly get rid of subjects in real practices. It seems impractical, or even impossible to do so.

Imagine a simple theoretical **weather app** that has just two things:

1. a view that displays current weather information
2. a refresh button which re-fetch the weather information from the server.

(Let's assume for simplicity that the app does not show the data at initial launch, but waits for the users to press refresh button at least once.)

Then you can think of a view model design like this:

**ViewModel**

```
interface IWeatherViewModel {

    // Provides weather data
    Flowable<WeatherData> getWeatherDataToDisplay();

    // Lets view to refresh
    void refresh();
}
```

If I use `Subject` then `IWeatherViewModel` can be implemented like this:

```
class WeatherViewModel implements IWeatherViewModel {

    private final BehaviorProcessor<WeatherData> weatherData = BehaviorProcessor.create();
    private final PublishProcessor<Boolean> eventRefresh = PublishProcessor.create();


    WeatherViewModel() {
        eventRefresh
            .flatMapSingle(x -> getWeatherData())
            .subscribe(weatherData);
    }


    // Provides weather data
    public Flowable<WeatherData> getWeatherDataToDisplay() {
        weatherData.hide();
    }

    // Lets view to refresh
    public void refresh() {
        eventRefresh.onNext(true);
    }



    private Single<WeatherData> getWeatherData() {
        ... // omitted for simplicity            
    }
}
```

The idea is to have a `PublishProcessor` that emits refresh event whenever `refresh()` is called which is then propagated to a `BehaviorSubject`. All subscribers that observe `getWeatherDataToDisplay()` will be notified once `getWeatherData()` is successful.

However I find it difficult to implement the same thing without `Subject`.

1. The app needs to propagate `refresh()` call to stream. I might be able to replace `PublishProcessor` using `Flowable.create()` but it doesn't look clean at all, the best I could do is:

```
private FlowableEmitter emitter;
private final Flowable<Boolean> eventRefresh = Flowable.create(emitter -> {
    this.emitter = emitter;
}, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);


public void refresh() {
    emitter.onNext(true);
}
```

Now suddenly I have to have a new instance variable that I cannot make final..

2. Also I am not able to find any operator that can effectively replace `BehaviorProcessor`, nor any hot observable that emits the latest item immediately on subscription. This behavior is necessary because the view should be able to detach and re-attach seamlessly, just like `LiveData`.

If you see any improvement that can be made, or have a different approach to the problem, please share your thougts.

Comment: You should not use a stream to propagate a directive. You can make a stream of click events but the click event observer should imperatively invoke getWeatherData() on your viewmodel.

Comment: @Vishal Arora, could you elaborate more on your point? If I call `getWeatherData()` directly, that means I am creating a new observer every time the user clicks on the button. That kind of destroys the MVVM architecture.

Comment: Creating a new observer does not defeat MVVM in any sense. If you want to keep the same observer then you need to decouple your request source and response sink. Currently, your method returns an observable to listen to the response. You can keep a separate `Response<Observable>` (similar to  LiveData in Android Architecture components) and just request using `getWeatherData()`. To couple these, you need to keep a source that Response<Observable> continues listens to.

Comment: @Vishal Arora, I agree that creating a new observer does not defeat MVVM in any sense. What I was trying to explain was that having multiple observers that  *each of them attached to different sources* kind of defeats MVVM. (My bad I did not say it clearly).

Comment: In my opinion, View must be completely stateless, and it must only depends on the ViewModel. This means if there are multiple View instances that are attached to the same ViewModel instance, the Views should be able to display the same exact thing, no matter when they started observation. But It seems to me in what you suggested, View has its own state, "did the user click on the refresh button or not".

Comment: @ Sanlok Lee did you find any other way to do it. I also have similar use case.

Comment: @Aditya Sharma sadly I gave up and I decided to just keep using `Subject` and `LiveData` for now. If you later find any solution, please leave an answer if possible. I will make sure to accept and upvote.